# Using two aggregate values from a SELECT subquery in a single outer SELECT query

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

For relevant tables and columns (a lot more exist than the following), I have a `customer` table with `cust_id` and `state`
columns and an `account` table with `account_id`, `cust_id`, and `avail_balance` columns.

Example `customer` table:

```
| cust_id | state |
|--------:|-------|
|       1 | MA    |
|       2 | MA    |
|       3 | MA    |
|       4 | MA    |
|       5 | NH    |
|       6 | MA    |
|       7 | MA    |
|       8 | NH    |
|       9 | MA    |
|      10 | NH    |
|      11 | MA    |
|      12 | NH    |
|      13 | MA    |
```

Example `account` table:

```
| account_id | cust_id | avail_balance |
|-----------:|--------:|--------------:|
|          1 |       1 |       1057.75 |
|          2 |       1 |           500 |
|          3 |       1 |          3000 |
|          4 |       2 |       2258.02 |
|          5 |       2 |           200 |
|          7 |       3 |       1057.75 |
|          8 |       3 |        2212.5 |
|         10 |       4 |        534.12 |
|         11 |       4 |        767.77 |
|         12 |       4 |       5487.09 |
|         13 |       5 |       2237.97 |
|         14 |       6 |        122.37 |
|         15 |       6 |         10000 |
|         17 |       7 |          5000 |
|         18 |       8 |       3487.19 |
|         19 |       8 |        387.99 |
|         21 |       9 |        125.67 |
|         22 |       9 |       9345.55 |
|         23 |       9 |          1500 |
|         24 |      10 |      23575.12 |
|         25 |      10 |             0 |
|         27 |      11 |       9345.55 |
|         28 |      12 |      38552.05 |
|         29 |      13 |         50000 |
```

Here is an example of a query that I wish to optimize.

```sql
SELECT account.cust_id
FROM account, customer
WHERE
      account.cust_id = customer.cust_id
  AND customer.state = 'MA'
  AND customer.cust_id >
      (SELECT MAX(customer.cust_id) AS max_nh_cust_id
       FROM account, customer
       WHERE
             account.cust_id = customer.cust_id
         AND state = 'NH')
  AND account.avail_balance >
      (SELECT MAX(avail_balance) AS max_nh_avail_balance
       FROM account, customer
       WHERE
             account.cust_id = customer.cust_id
         AND state = 'NH');
```

Expected result for the above example data (may not be just 1 result if data is different):

```
| cust_id |
|--------:|
|      13 |
```

The problem with the above is the code redundancy and how we have to iterate multiple times through the `account` table with the two subqueries. I was hoping that it would be possible to use one subquery to get the maximum `cust_id` and `avail_balance` from the `account` table and use those two scalars in the outer query. For example, the shape of the query might look something like this:

```sql
SELECT account.cust_id
FROM account, customer
WHERE
      account.cust_id = customer.cust_id
  AND (customer.cust_id > max_nh_cust_id AND account.avail_balance) > max_nh_avail_balance) IN
      (SELECT MAX(customer.cust_id) AS max_nh_cust_id, MAX(avail_balance) AS max_nh_avail_balance
       FROM account, customer
       WHERE
             account.cust_id = customer.cust_id
         AND state = 'NH');
```

Obviously, the above does not work. What is the most efficient way of implementing something like the above with less code redundancy and only in one query (that may contain subqueries)?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. It is rather unclear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @GMB I added sample data and the sample result

Comment: @RickJames Will do. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the 2 subqueries into 1:

```
SELECT MAX(c.cust_id) AS max_nh_cust_id,
       MAX(a.avail_balance) AS max_nh_avail_balance 
FROM account a INNER JOIN customer c 
ON a.cust_id = c.cust_id 
WHERE c.state = 'NH'
```

and join it like this:

```
SELECT a.cust_id
FROM account a 
INNER JOIN customer c ON a.cust_id = c.cust_id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(c.cust_id) AS max_nh_cust_id,
         MAX(a.avail_balance) AS max_nh_avail_balance 
  FROM account a INNER JOIN customer c 
  ON a.cust_id = c.cust_id 
  WHERE c.state = 'NH'
) t ON c.cust_id > t.max_nh_cust_id AND a.avail_balance > t.max_nh_avail_balance
WHERE c.state = 'MA'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=10ddb334161276987c9b0511ac31b60b).
Results:

```
> | cust_id |
> | ------: |
> |      13 |
```

Comment: Hi! I made a slight adjustment to my question to also ask about using the joined columns with aggregate function values. If you could append to your answer for this addition, I would appreciate it!

Comment: This is a new requirement and should be a new question.

Comment: I see. Will do!