# Unable to use single-valued column from subquery table join in HAVING clause with aggregate value

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

Related question upon which I based this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64411766/using-two-aggregate-values-from-a-select-subquery-in-a-single-outer-select-query)

For relevant tables and columns (a lot more exist than the following), I have a `customer` table with `cust_id` and `state` columns and an `account` table with `account_id`, `cust_id`, and `avail_balance` columns.

Example customer table:

```
| cust_id | state |
|--------:|-------|
|       1 | MA    |
|       2 | MA    |
|       3 | MA    |
|       4 | MA    |
|       5 | NH    |
|       6 | MA    |
|       7 | MA    |
|       8 | NH    |
|       9 | MA    |
|      10 | NH    |
|      11 | MA    |
|      12 | NH    |
|      13 | MA    |
```

Example account table:

```
| account_id | cust_id | avail_balance |
|-----------:|--------:|--------------:|
|          1 |       1 |       1057.75 |
|          2 |       1 |           500 |
|          3 |       1 |          3000 |
|          4 |       2 |       2258.02 |
|          5 |       2 |           200 |
|          7 |       3 |       1057.75 |
|          8 |       3 |        2212.5 |
|         10 |       4 |        534.12 |
|         11 |       4 |        767.77 |
|         12 |       4 |       5487.09 |
|         13 |       5 |       2237.97 |
|         14 |       6 |        122.37 |
|         15 |       6 |         10000 |
|         17 |       7 |          5000 |
|         18 |       8 |       3487.19 |
|         19 |       8 |        387.99 |
|         21 |       9 |        125.67 |
|         22 |       9 |       9345.55 |
|         23 |       9 |          1500 |
|         24 |      10 |      23575.12 |
|         25 |      10 |             0 |
|         27 |      11 |       9345.55 |
|         28 |      12 |      38552.05 |
|         29 |      13 |         50000 |
```

Here is the format of the query which I wish to execute.

```sql
SELECT a.cust_id, SUM(a.avail_balance) AS cust_tot_bal
FROM
    account AS a
    INNER JOIN customer c ON a.cust_id = c.cust_id
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(cust_id) AS max_nh_cust_id, MAX(nh_cust_tot_bal) AS max_nh_cust_tot_bal
                FROM
                    (SELECT a.cust_id, SUM(avail_balance) AS nh_cust_tot_bal
                     FROM
                         account AS a
                         INNER JOIN customer c ON a.cust_id = c.cust_id
                     WHERE
                         c.state = 'NH'
                     GROUP BY a.cust_id) AS nh_cust_tot_bal) AS max_nh_cust_tot_bal_t
WHERE c.state = 'MA'
AND a.cust_id > max_nh_cust_id
GROUP BY a.cust_id;
```

This fails since it is unable to detect `max_nh_cust_tot_bal` from the previous join.

Expected result for the above example data (the `cust_tot_bal` column is optional):

```
| cust_id | cust_tot_bal |
|--------:|-------------:|
|      13 |        50000 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the maximum `cust_id` and sum of the customers of state `'NH'` with this query:

```
SELECT MAX(cust_id) max_nh_cust_id, 
       MAX(t.max_nh_avail_balance) max_nh_avail_balance
FROM (
  SELECT a.cust_id, SUM(a.avail_balance) AS max_nh_avail_balance
  FROM account a INNER JOIN customer c 
  ON a.cust_id = c.cust_id
  WHERE c.state = 'NH'
  GROUP BY a.cust_id
) t
```

and you can join it like this:

```
SELECT m.cust_id, m.cust_tot_bal
FROM (
  SELECT a.cust_id, SUM(a.avail_balance) AS cust_tot_bal
  FROM account a INNER JOIN customer c 
  ON a.cust_id = c.cust_id
  WHERE c.state = 'MA'
  GROUP BY a.cust_id
) m  
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(cust_id) max_nh_cust_id, 
         MAX(t.max_nh_avail_balance) max_nh_avail_balance
  FROM (
    SELECT a.cust_id, SUM(a.avail_balance) AS max_nh_avail_balance
    FROM account a INNER JOIN customer c 
    ON a.cust_id = c.cust_id
    WHERE c.state = 'NH'
    GROUP BY a.cust_id
  ) t 
) n ON m.cust_id > n.max_nh_cust_id AND m.cust_tot_bal > n.max_nh_avail_balance
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fe3d2399a3b443147cc0e2c0c91fa5f6).
Results

```
> cust_id | cust_tot_bal
> ------: | -----------:
>      13 |        50000
```

Comment: Apologies. I forgot to add the max customer ID constraint from the previous question. The question has been updated accordingly.